# How do you find the UDID for an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, itunes, ipod-touch

How do you find the UDID for an iOS device on Mac and Windows?

Comment: Please provide screen shots as I'd like to share this with *very* non-technical people.

Comment: It's worth noting that Apple is trying to get iOS developers to move away from accessing/using the UDID for privacy reasons and as of [March 2012](http://techcrunch.com/2012/03/24/apple-udids/) is actively rejecting apps that do so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can follow the [official how-to from Apple KB](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4061).

The same way works for iPhone, iPod and iPad.

The easiest way is to plug your iDevice, open iTunes, click on your device on the left panel of iTunes then click on the serial number. Your UDID will appear :

[image: udid]

Comment: In iTunes 11, the method is the same, just the layout of the Summary pane is a bit different.

Comment: This answer is no longer useful, as iTunes is gone now! -- Either of the other two options are valid. (System Profiler, or using the Finder view and tapping below the device name so it cycles between different bits of information)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative for those who don't actually run iTunes (yes there are alternatives) is to open the `System Profiler`, access the `USB section`, find the iPhone on the list of connected devices under the USB device tree.

On the iPhone listing there will be an entry that says `serial number`. This is not to be confused with the serial number listed in the General -> About section of the iPhone settings. The serial in the System Profiler is equivalent to the UDID.

[image: System Report from System Information]

Note that on Lion, System Profiler has been renamed System Information and you can get the the USB information from the hardware portion of the System Report.

Comment: That's a priceless answer, as it was the only way to get the UDID of my phone after I upgraded to a beta version and forgot to add the UDID to the provisioning portal!!!

Answer (score 3):

This approach requires only a macOS device, the iOS device and the device's power cord.

If you have the iOS [paired to the macOS device through wi-fi](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/wi-fi-syncing-mchlada1d602/mac), you don't need a power cord and can skip steps 1 and 2.

This approach was based on macOS Catalina v10.15.5 and may not apply for other versions of the OS.

### Steps

1. Connect the iOS device to an USB port of your macOS device.
2. If the iOS device asks for permission to trust the macOS device, grant it (assuming it's a device you trust).
3. Open the Finder app.
4. Go to the iOS device in the Locations section of the sidebar. It should open the device's page.
5. Click on the info section bellow the iOS device name on the top of the page until it displays the UDID.

[image: The iOS device's page on Finder with an arrow pointing to the section where the UDID is.]

You can copy the UDID by right clicking on it.

[Source](https://medium.com/@igor_marques/how-to-find-an-iphones-udid-2d157f1cf2b9)

Answer (score 1):

While all the methods described so far require the iPhone/iPod Touch/iPad to be connected to a computer, there are a large number of free applications available in the App Store to find the UDID without needing to do this (and, thus, effectively working on Mac, Windows, and indeed anything else).

The one I use and generally recommend to remote clients is Erica Sadun's Ad Hoc Helper (screenshot, etc., at below link):

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ad-hoc-helper/id285691333?mt=8

Which extracts the UDID and places it in an e-mail ready to be sent to whoever needs it, but a quick search of the iTunes store for "UDID" reveals half a dozen or so apps all intended to do this and any of which would do the job.